# Is $A$ s.t $A_{i, j} = x^T_i x_j$ semi-positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and set define a $k$ by $k$ matrix $A$ by setting $A_{i, j} = x^T_i x_j$. Is $A$ semi-positive definite? If so, how can I show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t:=(t_1,\dots,t_k)\in\mathbb R^k$. Then 
$$t^TAt=\sum_{i,j=1}^kx_i^Tx_jt_it_j=\sum_{i,j=1}^k((t_ix_i)^T)\cdot (t_jx_j)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^k(t_ix_i)^T\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{j=1}^kt_jx_j\right),$$
which is the square of the Euclidian norm of $\sum_{j=1}^kt_jx_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote matrix $G=\left(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k\right)$, then $A=G^TG$. Apparently $A$ is positive semi-definite.

The second method. By definition, you wanna show for any $y\in\mathbb R^n$, $y^TAy\geq 0$. Or
$$\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}y_iy_j=\sum_{i,j}\left(\sum_kx_{i,k}x_{j,k}\right)y_iy_j=\sum_k\left(\sum_ix_{i,k}y_i\sum_jx_{j,k}y_j\right)=\sum_k\left(\sum_ix_{i,k}y_i\right)^2\geq0$$
which is precisely what we want.